# CKEditor não reconhece atributo required

Tags: javascript, html5, formulário, ckeditor

Estou utilizando o CKEditor para criar páginas que podem conter formulários (em outras palavras, [formulários podem ser inseridos no conteúdo sendo editado](http://ckeditor.com/addon/forms), pois estou usando o *full package*). Gostaria de poder utilizar o atributo [`required`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-required) em alguns campos dos formulários sendo editados (ele [é suportado pela maioria dos *browsers* modernos](http://caniuse.com/#search=required), e no meu caso uma solução via JavaScript seria no mínimo inconveniente<sup>1</sup>), só que o CKEditor não só não oferece essa opção como também - ao tentar [editar o fonte diretamente](http://ckeditor.com/addon/sourcedialog) - **remove** esse atributo se eu tentar colocá-lo "à força".

Pra piorar a situação, o CKEditor não permite que se adicione classes aos `input`s, também removendo-as caso eu as coloque direto no fonte (tem algum jeito de desabilitar isso?). Só me resta fazer gambiarras ainda maiores pra chegar onde eu quero (viável, contudo; não precisa sugerir isso em resposta, pois já tenho alguns meios em mente).

Há algum meio de "forçar" o CKEditor a aceitar esse atributo? Nem que pra isso eu tenha que desabilitar outras validações que essa ferramenta faz? Ou isso é algo específico do `contentEditable`, e cada *browser* vai fazer do seu jeito sem possibilidade de customização?

<sub>1. Esclarecendo: não é problema pra mim colocar um JavaScript "genérico" que atue igualmente em qualquer página criada, o inconveniente é ter que criar um código JS específico pra cada formulário que for criado (pois isso é uma funcionalidade a ser oferecida **para o cliente!**).</sub>

Comment: Pelo que vi nos códigos referentes parece proposital para forçar a usar o sistema de validação deles, talvez só um hack/patch no código principal.

Comment: O `required` estaria no próprio campo editável? Achei um [bug report](https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/8031) falando disso, mas consta como resolvido.

Comment: @bfavaretto Pelo que eu entendi, esse bug report se refere ao `textarea` que é convertido em um editor via `$("#textarea").ckeditor(...)`, e não ao conteúdo do mesmo sendo editado pelo usuário. No conteúdo (modo *full*) pode-se incluir várias coisas, inclusive outros formulários, e é nos campos desses formulários que eu preciso eventualmente colocar o atributo `required`.

Comment: A propósito, o CKEditor foi concebido pensando no HTML4, de modo que sua validação rejeita muita coisa considerada válida pelo HTML5. Eu tenho pouca esperança desse tipo de suporte ser oferecido num futuro próximo, mas eu espero conseguir um meio de desabilitar algumas validações de modo a conseguir inserir o que eu quero (e de preferência preservar, entre uma edição e outra). Minhas pesquisas até agora levaram pro [`protectedSource`](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.protectedSource), talvez por aí exista uma solução, em breve devo fazer uns testes...

Comment: Sim, o bug é no textarea a ser convertido. Não estava claro pra mim se você estava falando desse campo ou do próprio conteúdo do editor, agora entendi que é o segundo caso.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A configuração [`extraAllowedContent`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/?_escaped_fragment_=/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-extraAllowedContent) permite ampliar os filtros<sup>1</sup> que determinam o que é ou não aceito no markup tratado pelo CKEditor. Para se permitir o atributo `required` em `input`s e `textarea`s, por exemplo, pode-se usar essa configuração:

```
CKEDITOR.config.extraAllowedContent = 'input[required];' + 
                                      'textarea[required];';
```

No caso usei uma configuração global, mas poderia também fazê-lo em um editor específico.

<sub>1. Esses filtros são os mesmos [citados por Michel Simões em sua resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/58518/215) (que me indicou na direção correta para chegar a esta solução).</sub>

Comment: Como posso implementar o required neste codigo?

<textarea required id='editor33'  name='descricao' rows="5" style='width:600px;height:700px;' ></textarea>
    <script>
                CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor33' );
            </script>

Comment: @saimita Não entendi o que quis dizer. Isso tem alguma coisa a ver com essa resposta? Se não, sugiro abrir uma nova pergunta, descrevendo sua dúvida com mais detalhes.

Comment: tenho uma textarea ckeditor e cria  que fosse required

Comment: @saimita Ah, entendi. Realmente, isso não tem nada a ver com essa pergunta - pois ela se trata de colocar o atributo `required` no **conteúdo** de um editor. Para fazer o editor em si ser *required*, eu não sei como é... :(

Answer (score 3):

Voce pode usar a propriedade filter.check para verificar se há algum texto, por exemplo para verificar se há imagem no texto:
filter.check( 'img[alt]' ); // -> true
 ou se vc quiser pode usar 
filter.check( '', true, true ); // -> true
que ele retornará false se o campo estiver em branco.

Comment: Não entendi como isso resolve meu problema. Esse filtro poderia ser aplicado individualmente a cada campo? *Pelo próprio editor* (ou de uma maneira que ele fosse preservado entre edições)? Essa parte é importante... Pois como expliquei na pergunta, não dá pra colocar código JS específico pra cada formulário, apenas um código genérico que atue igualmente em todo formulário criado.

Comment: se voce configurar nas properties genéricas do ckeditor, la na classe construtora dele, todas as instancias receberão o filtro antes de submeter o formulário será verificado. se vc atribuir no construtor do ckeditor na tela, poderá atribuir manualmente para cada um.

Comment: Valeu, sua resposta me deu a dica que eu precisava pra resolver (no fim usei `extraAllowedContent` em vez de filtros)! No começo eu tinha entendido que era algo a ser aplicado nos `input`s - e não no editor como um todo...